# Power BI: Dynamic text (not from slicer)

Tags: filter, powerbi, textbox

I have a 'Store Location' slicer from one excel sheet connecting to another sheet with the same column 'Store Location'.  There is a text box that prints the information but will not print some text.

I watched several YouTube tutorials (mainly 'Guy in a cube' slicer / dynamic text videos other similar ones) but could not find this example.  Their examples pulled text from the slicer which mine does not.  If this question was already asked, if you can point me to the source, that will help

This is my data (from excel file):

```
StoreData
Store Location,Attribute,Value
LA,R1,5 
LA,R2,7
LA,R3,2
NY,R1,6
NY,R2,9
NY,R3,8
SF,R1,1
SF,R2,2
SF,R3,3

StoreInfo
StoreLocation,Mgr,BackupManager,#workers
LA,John Smith,Mr A,30
LA,John Smith,Mr B,30
NY,Roger Adams,Mr S,40
SF,Mary Jones,Miss Q,60
SF,Mary Jones,Miss Y,60
```

Here is the model: [image]

I have a slicer from StoreData (location) to StoreInfo(location)
#workers prints correctly but for locations with multiple backup managers, only one is printed.  LA has 2 backup managers but only one prints.

[image]

I added the value by clicking '+ Value' and typing 'backup manager'

Does anyone know how the textbox can print the correct backup managers for a selection?

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Can you share a sample .pbix?